# What is the return type of my VBScript function?

Tags: vbscript, return-type, type-mismatch

This question is mostly out of interest to understand the functionality of VBScript better. I recognize that I can simply do some casting to know what to expect from my code, but in my situation I want to understand why casting, or any "workaround", is needed. For simplicity, here's the basic idea of my code:

```
variable1 = 1

Public Function findSomethingInATextString(par1, par2)
    [...searching with a Do Until loop code here...]
    Result = 1
    If([par2 is found in par1]) Then
        Result = 0
    End If
    Return Result
End Function

variable1 = findSomethingInATextString("Hello World", "Hello")
```

When I run this I get a `Type Mismatch` error. I don't understand why that's the case. `variable1` is an integer and `findSomethingInAString()` returns an integer. They appear to be the same data type.

I'm working in a restricted environment where I can't do much debugging (it's painfully slow to code in this program...). So at the moment I'm unable to say what data type this is coming out as - I just know that it's apparently not integer.

After all that, and to make sure my question is clear, I'm intrigued to know what the return type of my function is (if someone happens to know), but **my real question is**: Why isn't the return type matching with variable1?

Comment: This isn't VBScript. In VBScript, `Variant` is the only data type. Please tag this with the correct language.

Comment: Hem, if your pseudocode should be _VBScript_… There is no `Return` statement in _VBScript_.  A function returns a value by assigning a value to its name in one or more statements of the procedure. Use `findSomethingInAString = Result` instead of `Return Result` and omit word _string_ in `Public Function findSomethingInAString( par1, par2)`

Comment: Oh oops. Just a habit to put "string" in the parameter part. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Josef, I had to read your comment a few times. I'm no newbie to scripting, I'm not that experienced either, but I guess you're right! That return statement is making a mess of things. I've been switching between vba and vbs too much the past few day. I didn't even notice. Thank you! Could you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the minimal script

```
Return
```

Output

```
cscript 36633603.vbs
...36633603.vbs(1, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'return'
```

to prove to yourself, that just mentioning `return` in a VBScript will throw a type mismatch error.

Believe JosefZ's comment that VBScript returns function values by assigning to the function's name. Better: Read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (before you try to write code).

Evidence:

```
Function f1()
  f1 = 1
End Function

WScript.Echo f1(), TypeName(f1())
```

Output:

```
cscript 36633603.vbs
1 Integer
```

Comment: Thanks @Ekkehard, that's an interesting test to do. I do believe JosefZ and did read the docs, it was just one of those days where I was writing code in 3 different languages for 3 different projects and habitually wrote `return` without thinking.